# Need help to add more option in polls module in phpfox

Tags: phpfox

i checked the script of existing option like All Polls, My Polls etc  all these coming from xml with some integer value. But I don't know how to add new option. For reference i attached screen-sort.

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Those dont come from an xml file, check the file /module/poll/include/component/controller/index.class.php in there look for "buildMenu"

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to poll index controller:

   module/poll/include/component/controller/index.class.php
2. Find  `$this->template()->buildSectionMenu('poll', $aFilterMenu);`
3. You can add more options in the list by adding items in `$aFilterMenu` array

   eg :  `$aFilterMenu['xyz'] = 'xyz';`